# Send files as message in JeroMQ

Tags: java, zeromq, jeromq

In JeroMQ how to send files with content type of file and other properties with single message.

in client:

build file message and send to server

```
DataInputStream inStrm = file.getContent();
ZMsg msg = ZMsg.load(inStrm);
msg.send(sender);
```

Is there any way to set properties to the message? like:

```
msg.setProperties("Content-Type", "application/xml");
msg.setProperties("fileName", "abc.pdf");
```

and in server, receive file:

```
Poller items = new ZMQ.Poller (2);
items.register(receiver, ZMQ.Poller.POLLIN);
while (true) {
    try{
        items.poll();       
        if (items.pollin(0)) {
            ZMsg msg = ZMsg.recvMsg(receiver);
            //save file to disk
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        LOG.error("Error while receive file: ", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand `ZMsg.load` is for re-loading messages that have previously been saved to file with `ZMsg.save`, not for sending arbitrary data  from a file.

Comment: and, what is the method used for sending file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another way. ZeroMq has [Multipart-Messages](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Multipart-Messages)

It is very useful in my opinion.
In jeromq/jzmq libs you can use it in this way:

Store a data from file in byte array.
Make a multipart ZMsg, put all headers and data you need inside:

```
ZMsg outMsg = new ZMsg();
outMsg.add(new ZFrame("application/xml"));
outMsg.add(new ZFrame("abc.pdf"));
outMsg.add(new ZFrame(bytes)); // here is the data from file
outMsg.send(outSocket);
```

Receive ZMsg from another socket and get all data from it:

```
ZMsg inMsg = ZMsg.recvMsg(inSocket);
String contentType = inMsg.pop().toString();
String fileName = inMsg.pop().toString();
byte[] fileData = inMsg.pop().getData();
```

Or you can do it in any other convenient way, by serializing all necessary headers in one byte array and using only two frames, etc.